# pylint raising R0801 for coding declaration lines

Tags: python, pylint

I have a Python project and am using the following line in some files:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

When I use pylint, it complains with a R0801 warning saying that there are many files with this same code. What's the best way to make pylint ignore these?

Comment: weird. You must have subsequent pattern below, no ? Similarities should be at least 4 subsequent lines.

Comment: No it's complaining about this line being used in multiple files.

Comment: and no configuration overrides for min-similarity-lines ? If so, probably worth discussing it on python-projects@lists.logilab.org, providing a minimal case demonstrating the pb.

Comment: I regretfully didn't disclose that I'm using the Violations plugin for Jenkins to integrate pylint. I have a feeling the plugin is broken and isn't parsing the pylint output properly, and is displaying the R0801 messages in the wrong places.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, the root cause of this problem with Jenkins Violations scanner is that it does not properly parse Pylint output in this case and all code duplications are assigned to first line of one file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the issue if you use this syntax for encoding declaration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I had originally and decided to clean it up and use the shorter form.

Answer (score 0):

Since utf-8 is the default encoding in Python 3.0+, you can remove these lines.

[PEP 3120 -- Using UTF-8 as the default source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/k)